# Informix - how to release memory?

Tags: memory-management, informix

When I delete rows, those rows are only marked to be deleted and the new data can be saved there, but it is possible to force releasing memory ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is really disk space rather than memory that you're worried about, I think.  The memory used by a deleted row is only part of a page image (or several page images if the row size is big enough).

Second, there isn't really a way to release the disk space associated with the row.  All the disk space allocated to the chunk remains in use. It was in use before the row was created and remains in use after the row is deleted.  Informix handles the allocation.

What is the concern?  You won't run out of space either within Informix or at the o/s level because of a deleted row.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Informix version you can use SQL administration API commands
for storage optimization and consolidate free space in tables.

Use repack operation online or offline and table shrink or defragment partition extents.

V11.50 or above

•   Repack moves rows from the end of the partition to the empty page space present in the upper end of the partition.

•   Shrink releases extents that have been emptied back to the dbspace.

V12.10

•   Defragment tables or indexes to merge non-contiguous extents.

See :

Administrator's Guide Manage disk space chapter

Administrator's Reference SQL Administration API Functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reclaim the storage space occupied by deleted rows, you can unload the table, delete the table, re-create the table, load the unloaded rows into the empty new table you just re-created, re-create the indexes, and update the table's statistics. Note, this will also optimize the table for improved performance.